ModuleNotFoundError When Importing Local Package After Installing Python Project Locally
I am packaging my first python project, and I have two files with helper functions, comments.py and score.py  stored in the subdirectory.
YT_Sentiments/
└── src/
    ├── YT_Sentiments/
    │   ├── helpers/
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── score.py
    │   │   └── comments.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── main.py
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── README.md
    └── setup.py

in my main.py I import the two files
from helpers import score
from helpers import comments

When I build and install it locally, I get the error:
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\YT_Sentiments\main.py", line  
1, in <module>
from helpers import score
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'

I have followed atleast 4 tutorials on packaging and implemented what I thought would solve my problem (setup.py)
python setup.py bdist_wheel sdist

setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

with open("README.md") as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(name = "YT_Sentiments",
      version = "0.0.4",
      description = "analyze comments from any youtube video!",
      package_dir = {"YT_Sentiments":"YT_Sentiments",
                 "YT_Sentiments.helpers":"YT_Sentiments/helpers",},
      packages = ['YT_Sentiments', 'YT_Sentiments.helpers'],
      long_description=long_description,
      long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
      license = "MIT",
      classifiers=[
                   "Programming Language :: Python",
                   "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
                   "Operating System :: OS Independent",
                   ],
      install_requires = ["emoji>=2.12.1",
                          "google_api_python_client>=2.139.0",
                          "vaderSentiment>=3.3.2",
                          "vaderSentiment>=3.3.2",],
      python_requires = ">=3.8",  
    )


I found the solution to the problem. I only needed to change two lines of code:
The issue is in main.py:
from helpers import score
from helpers import comments

change it to:
from YT_Sentiments.helpers import score
from YT_Sentiments.helpers import comments

This is all the required change to fix my problem. My package (YT_Sentiments) is now on PyPI and it works as normal.

First, make sure you have installed the module
pip install helpers

Note that the module you are using has not been updated for a long time.
Then make sure that the version of the module is compatible with the version of Python and pip
python --version

pip --version


it seems I fumbled with the import statements. I changed it and now it works. Thanks for the help!
